# MutableLiveData won't trigger loadAfter to fetch from Android ROM using PagedList

Tags: android, pagedlist, mutablelivedata, android-rom, android-pagedlistview

I have 70 itens stored on my ROM and I would like to fetch a paged amount of 15. I read many posts so far with related issues, however none of them were useful for me.

Some possible causes for `loadAfter` not being triggered:

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51359214/1573036) : call `getItem` inside `onBindViewHolder`

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53578337/1573036) : call `submitList` to `PagedListAdapter`

[Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020921/android-paging-library-doesnt-fire-loadafter) : replace `ListAdapter` with `PagedListAdapter`

I assume `DataBinding` is fine since everything works without trying to paging.

I'm mocking my data source to understand what's happening. Some functions are suspended 'cause they should have data coming from ROM which requires it. My code state be like:

**ADAPTER**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    getItem(position).let { wkda ->
        with(holder) {
            wkda?.apply { bind(createOnClickListener(this)) }
        }
    }
}
```

**FRAGMENT**

```
vm.manufacturers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { manufacturers ->            
            adapter.submitList(manufacturers)
}
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
var manufacturers: MutableLiveData<PagedList<WKDA>> = MutableLiveData()

init {
  viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.getManufacturers(manufacturers)
  }
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
suspend fun getManufacturers(manufacturers: MutableLiveData<PagedList<WKDA>>) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            manufacturers.postValue(ManufacturerPagedList.
                getInstance().
                fetchPage())
        }
}
```

**MANUFACTURER PAGED LIST**

```
private val executor = ManufacturerExecutor()

private val paginationConfig: PagedList.Config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
        .setPrefetchDistance(FETCH_DISTANCE)
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .build()

companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: ManufacturerPagedList? = null
            fun getInstance() = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                ManufacturerPagedList().also {
                    instance = it
                }
        }
    }

fun fetchPage(): PagedList<WKDA> = PagedList.Builder<Int, WKDA>(
            MockDataSource(),
            paginationConfig)
            .setInitialKey(INITIAL_KEY)
            .setFetchExecutor(executor)
            .setNotifyExecutor(executor)
            .build()
}
```

**DATASOURCE**

```
class MockDataSource : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, WKDA>() {
    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Int>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, WKDA>) {
        callback.onResult(List(20) { generatePost(params.requestedLoadSize) }.toList(), -1, 1)
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, WKDA>) {
        callback.onResult(List(20) { generatePost(params.key) }.toList(), params.key + 1)
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, WKDA>) {
        callback.onResult(List(20) { generatePost(params.key) }.toList(), params.key - 1)
    }

    private fun generatePost(key: Int): WKDA {
        return WKDA("name", "author $key")
    }
}
```

**CONSTANTS**

```
const val INITIAL_KEY: Int = 0
const val PAGE_SIZE: Int = 15
const val FETCH_DISTANCE: Int = 1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure loadAfter is not being triggered? What comes into my mind is it can get called, but new items from list are equal to the ones being already in adapter, so the new ones are no added

Comment: Please post as an answer: `return WKDA("name", "author $key")` every mock object was being settle as `"name"` and `DiffCallback` was comparing `wkda.id` which has always the `"name"` value. Also sort of what happened to itens from `ROM`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After check: loadAfter was called properly. The problem was model itself:

> wkda.id had always the same "name" value

DiffCallback compared old list of objects with the new one and didn't see differences, so the item "duplicates" weren't added to the adapter